# form submit with jquery gets out from the facebook canvas?

Tags: jquery, facebook-iframe, facebook-canvas

a little help required in my facebook application, i have two sub,it buttons in a page, so i am submitting my form with jquery, everything is working fine, but when i test it in the facebook canvas, i took me out of the canvas which i dont want, my form action was

```
<?site_url('controller/function')?>
```

then i change the form action as

```
https://apps.facebook.com/my_app_name/controller/function
```

trick works, i stayed in canvas, but my data was not posted this time! here is my code,

```
<input type="submit" name="Something1" id="Something1" value="Something1" onclick="checkType('type1', '<?=site_url()?>');return false;">
<input type="submit" name="Something2" id="Something2" value="Something2" onclick="checkType('type2', '<?=site_url()?>');return false;">
```

and jquery function is,

```
function checkType(type, url) {
   if(type == type1) {
    $('#my_form').attr("action", url+'controller/function');
    $('#my_form').submit();
    } else {
    $('#my_form').attr("action", url+'controller/function2');
    $('#my_form').submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your submit type for button, and then add the attribute target as follow, and remove the return false like that:

```
<input type="button" target="_self" name="Something1" id="Something1" value="Something1" onclick="checkType('type1', '<?=site_url()?>');">
```